# Extracting all DATES from a .txt file

Tags: java, regex

hopefully this is short and to the question.. 
In the below program I have successfully extracted ALL data from a notepad doc named "pad.txt", which consists of 3 sets vertically aligned with an 'ID' followed by 'Name' followed by 'Date Joined', that pattern is consistent.

The notepad doc consists solely of this: 
dID: 1
Name: Bob 
Date Joined: 01/12/2014
ID: 2
Name: Jim 
Date Joined: 8/21/1993
ID: 3
Name: Steve
Date Joined: 6/07/2016

I have also defined a regex that accepts an acceptable date format: 1-2 digits, a slash, 1-2 digits again, a slash, then 2 to four digits for YEAR date.. At the beginning of that I specified a wild card character "." <- the dot with a greedy quantifier "*" the star, to say ANY number of ANY character before the date is accepted, as well as after the date I have also specified the ".*"

My main goal with this code is to EXTRACT ONLY all of the DATES within the pad.txt file, and store them in a String or something..

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("pad.txt")); 

//      Define valid date format via regex 
    String dateRegex = ".* (\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{2,4}) .* ";

        int fileContent = 0;
//      iterate through entire notepad doc, until = 0 AKA (finished searching doc) 
    while((fileContent = reader.read()) !=-1){

        builder.append((char)fileContent); 

      }//encapsulating loop 
    reader.close(); 

    String extracted = builder.toString(); 
    System.out.println("Extracted: " + extracted);
    System.out.println();

        Matcher m = null; 
//          Validate that file contents conform with 'dateRegex' 
        m = Pattern.compile(dateRegex).matcher(extracted);      
        if(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Entire group : " + m.group());  
        }   
  }
   }
```

Unfortunately, the m.group(); outprint only returns:
"Entire group : 6/07/2016" 
As stated, my goal is to extract ALL of the dates, but I can't fiddle with all of the dates if the .matcher call ONLY catches the "Entire group : 6/07/2016"
In my mind, I say ANY character of ANY amount is allowed before and AFTER the date, so it scrolls to the very bottom and finds ONLY the LAST date, how do I defined the regex so that it pulls out ALL of the dates, not just the very LAST one, and why is it only pulling the last one?

I've tried relentlessly with this and cannot figure out how..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's relatively easy. You can't write a regex that matches all dates at once, but you can use matcher as it was intended to be used, i.e. `find()` returns `true` as often as another match can be found. 
So you have to modify your regex and remove the `.*` on both ends. Then you can simply do this:

```
StringBuilder dateListBuilder = new Stringbuilder();
while(m.find()){
    dateListBuilder.append(m.group());
}
System.out.println(dateListBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: AH! It was that simple, I knew my .group implementation had to be slightly wrong, thanks so much! With this I've made even further strides to regex understandings :)